Unity Netcode How to call ServerRPC method of another script?
I need to call a ServerRPC method from a player script that is in another class. Here is an example of my code:
DashT.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;

public class DashT : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [ServerRpc]
    public void UseServerRpc()
    {
        Debug.Log(1);
    }
}

TestUseScript.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestUseScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GameObject obj = new GameObject();
        obj.name = string.Format("_{0}", typeof(DashT).Name);
        DashT skill = obj.AddComponent<DashT>();

        if (IsOwner)
            skill.UseServerRpc();
    }
}

I thought it would work but I got an error:
KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'DashT' was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].get_Item (TKey key) (at <20deccf348554c238921b06fec015ff8>:0)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkBehaviour.__endSendServerRpc (Unity.Netcode.FastBufferWriter& bufferWriter, System.UInt32 rpcMethodId, Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams, Unity.Netcode.RpcDelivery rpcDelivery) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.8.1/Runtime/Core/NetworkBehaviour.cs:127)
DashT.UseServerRpc () (at Assets/Scripts/Skills/DashT.cs:11)
TestUseScript.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Player/TestUseScript.cs:15)

How to fix it?

I dont think they changed it but you cant add networkbehaviours to network objects at run time,

I don't really understand the specific problem, but it was decided to create a prefab. The prefab should contain my script, in which I call ServerRPC, as well as NetworkObject. Then, at the beginning of work, I should create on server an object in the scene from the prefab and set Ownership the client, then using NetworkManager.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects to create an object on the clients.
TestUseScript.cs
public class TestUseScript : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private DashT _skill;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
    private bool _skillActivated = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        SpawnDashServerRpc();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (IsOwner && !_skillActivated && _skill != null)
        {
            _skill.UseServerRpc();
            _skillActivated = true;
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    private void SpawnDashServerRpc()
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab);
        NetworkObject networkObject = obj.GetComponent<NetworkObject>();

        _skill = networkObject.GetComponent<DashT>();

        networkObject.SpawnWithOwnership(OwnerClientId);
        SpawnDashClientRpc(networkObject.NetworkObjectId);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void SpawnDashClientRpc(ulong networkObjectId)
    {
        NetworkObject networkObject = NetworkManager.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects[networkObjectId];
        _skill = networkObject.GetComponent<DashT>();
    }
}

